# Meteor collection select WHERE

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to query mongo db where a field equals a certain value.

```
db.votes.find( { "userID": "a6MtLKmDYbiKXccXC" }, { name: 1 } );
```

returns what I need in the mongo shell.

When I try the following in my javascript though, it is returning an empty array.

```
var seen = Votes.find({ "userID": "a6MtLKmDYbiKXccXC" }, { name: 1 }).fetch();


Meteor.publish("votes", function(args) {
        var sub = this;

        var db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db;

        var pipeline = [
          { "$group": {
            "_id": "$name",
            "likes": { "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$vote", 1 ] },1,0] } },
            "dislikes": { "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$vote", 2 ] },1,0] } },
            "total": { "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$vote", 1 ] },1,-1] } }
          }},
          { "$sort": { "total": -1, "_id": 1 } }

        ];

        db.collection("votes").aggregate(
          pipeline,
          Meteor.bindEnvironment(
            function(err, result) {
              _.each(result, function(e) {
                e.name = e._id;
                delete e._id;

                sub.added("cardStore",Random.id(), e);

              });
              sub.ready();
            },
            function(error) {
              Meteor._debug( "error running: " + error);
            }
          )
        );
    });
```

Comment: Did you publish the votes to the client? What does `Votes.find().count()` return from the web console?

Comment: it returns 14 as it should

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the **autopublish** package? If not, you need to have publish methods server side and corresponding subscribe calls on your client side to make sure you have the data you need to run this query.

[Meteor Publish and Subscribe Documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish)

I would recommend using **msavin:mongol** package to debug data and subscriptions in your browser.

Side Note: You can use findOne as a short hand if you are going to call fetch with a collection of 1.

```
var seen = Votes.findOne({ "userID": "a6MtLKmDYbiKXccXC" }, { name: 1 });
```